# Looping through JSON data.d

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, json

**`data.d` =**

```
[
  {
    "NodeId": "BK01",
    "NodeName": "Books",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Likes": null
  },
  {
    "NodeId": "CO01",
    "NodeName": "Computers",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Likes": null
  },
  {
    "NodeId": "GA01",
    "NodeName": "Gaming",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Likes": null
  },
  {
    "NodeId": "MO01",
    "NodeName": "Mobile & Accessories",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Likes": null
  }
]
```

**WebService**

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function getCategories() As String
        Dim details As New List(Of Nodes)()
        Dim index As New Default2
        Using ds As Data.DataSet = index.db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, "SELECT NodeID,NodeName FROM Nodes WHERE ParentID='1'")
            Dim JaggedArray As String()() = New String(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)() {}
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each rs As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim node As New Nodes()
                node.NodeId = rs("NodeId").ToString
                node.NodeName = rs("NodeName").ToString
                details.Add(node)
                'JaggedArray(i) = New String() {rs("NodeName").ToString(), rs("NodeID").ToString()}
                i = i + 1
            Next
        End Using
        Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim strJSON As String = js.Serialize(details.ToArray)
        Return strJSON

    End Function
```

**AJAX Call**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //alert("!!!");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default2.aspx/getCategories",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var nodes = eval(data);
                alert(data.NodeName);
                $('#output').text(data.d);
                $.each(data.d, function(index, node) {
                $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + node.NodeName + ' ' +
                            node.NodeID + '</strong><br /> ');
                });
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to loop through `data.d` to get the values? `data.d.length` gives me `219` but it should be 4 ? What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $.map for E.G.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/--service--",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $.map(data.d, function (item) {
                $("#name").append('<option value=' + item.ID+ '>' + item.Name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry it does not work..i have updated my question with the `Ajax Call` ...kindly check it.

Comment: first create method that return object list dont need to return jsons-string .

Comment: ant try again alert using `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` now what it return ?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through data.d by using:

```
$.each(data.d, function(index, Value)
{
      //
});
```

But as you are returning a string so I think it won't work for you, its better that you return an array of string.
=======================EDIT====================
Make a new class like:

```
public class MyClass
{
      public MyNodes as Nodes()
}
```

and in your code of `getCategories` do it like:

```
Dim details As New List(Of Nodes)()
    Dim index As New Default2
Dim myObj As New MyClass
    Using ds As Data.DataSet = index.db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, "SELECT NodeID,NodeName FROM Nodes WHERE ParentID='1'")
        Dim JaggedArray As String()() = New String(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)() {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each rs As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim node As New Nodes()
            node.NodeId = rs("NodeId").ToString
            node.NodeName = rs("NodeName").ToString
myObj.Add(node)
            'details.Add(node)
            'JaggedArray(i) = New String() {rs("NodeName").ToString(), rs("NodeID").ToString()}
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End Using
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim strJSON As String = js.Serialize(myObj)
    Return strJSON
```

I am a C# guy not a VB.NET guy so might be there is some problem in code, which I am sure you can check

Comment: how do i return an array of string??